# react-native-video doesn't work with muted=true

Tags: react-native

I used react-native-video with property muted= true but it doesn't works can someone help me ?

```
   <Video source={{ uri: "************************" }}
            style={{ width: 0, height: 0 }}
            muted={true}

          />
```

Comment: Is this same [issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/pull/1699)?   what is your version?

Comment: version react-native-video = 4.4.5

Comment: It's looks PR in [5.1.0@alpha](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/1973) , but not sure if it is recommend using it  > <" ?  If you don't have any solution, maybe could try...

Comment: but to load the live streaming it take time how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

We can set videoVolume to zero or full(1.0) on tapping mute button like this:

```
const [videoVolume, setVideoVolume] = useState(1.0);

<Video 
          onEnd={onEnd}
          onLoad={onLoad}
          onLoadStart={onLoadStart}
          onProgress={onProgress}
          volume={videoVolume}
  />


  <TouchableOpacity
           onPress={() => {
                 if (muteSound === true) {
                     setMuteSound(false);
                     setVideoVolume(1.0);
                 } else {
                     setMuteSound(true);
                     setVideoVolume(0.0);
                 }
           }}
   >
   <Text>Mute</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73137125/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)